# Mathematical error concerning arrays and classes

Tags: c++

I have the code working for the most part (aside from the math issues), I just don't know where my math is going wrong.  It gives me the correct values for the first set of data but the second set is way off. 
Here is my header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class TestGrader

{
private:
    char correct_ans[20];
    int correct = 0;
public:
    void setCorrect_answers(char cans[]);
    void grade(char ans[]);
};
```

Here is my .cpp file

```
#include "TestGrader.h"

using namespace std;

/*******************************************************
*                      setCorrect_answers             *
* This member function receives a 20-character string *
* and copies its information into the answers array.  *
*******************************************************/
void TestGrader::setCorrect_answers(char cans[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i< 20 ; i++)
        correct_ans[i] = cans[i];
}

/*******************************************************
*                       grade                         *
* The grade function receives a 20-character array    *
* holding the test taker's answers and compares each  *
* of their answers to the correct one. The function   *
* then calculates and displays the results.           *
*******************************************************/
void TestGrader::grade(char ans[])
{
    cout << "User answer\t" << "Correct answer\t" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << ans[i] << "\t\t\t" << correct_ans[i] << "\t\t\t";
        if (ans[i] == correct_ans[i])
        {
            correct++;
        }
        else
            cout << "X";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    if (correct > 15)
        cout << "Congrats! You have passed the exam" << endl;
    else
        cout << "You have failed the exam. Better luck next time!" << endl;
    cout << "Number of correct answers: " << correct << endl;
    cout << "Number of wrong answers: " << 20 - correct  << endl;
}
```

And here is my tester (which contains main).  My teacher provided this so nothing should be changed here.

```
// Chapter 8 - Programming Challenge 11, Driver's License Exam
// This program utilizes a TestGrader class to grade the written portion of a 
// driver's license exam. The class grade function compares the applicant's 
// answers, stored in one array, to the correct answers, stored in another array.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include "TestGrader.h"

// ***************** Class tester ***************

int main()
{
    const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;
    int correct = 0;



    // Create a TestGrader object & set its key with correct answers
    char correct_ans[] = { 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C',
        'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
        'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',
        'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A' };

    // Array to hold test taker's answers
    char user1_ans[20] = { 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C',
        'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
        'A', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',
        'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A' };

    char user2_ans[20] = { 'A', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C',
        'A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'D',
        'A', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'C',
        'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'A' };

    TestGrader DMVexam;

    DMVexam.setCorrect_answers(correct_ans);

    //------------- Grade grade User 1's answers ---------
    cout << "------------ User # 1 -------------\n";
    DMVexam.grade(user1_ans);
    //------------- Grade grade User 2's answers ---------
    cout << "\n------------ User # 2 -------------\n";
    DMVexam.grade(user2_ans);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not resetting `correct` to 0 between grading students.

Comment: I'm trying to look up how to reset in my notes and I'm not finding anything.  Do you have any suggestions on where to go because I don't think we've actually been taught how to reset so I'd like to learn how.

Comment: "Reset" was English for "assign" `correct = 0`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `correct` to 0 at the beginning of the `grade()` method.

Comment: Also, in `setCorrect_answers()` you should use `memcpy()`, not a loop.